# belongs_to with :class_name behaving odd

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a Task model and User model.

A task can be assigned a user to process it, while a user can be assigned many tasks.

The field names are a little off so I am trying to use the class_name options etc, but for whatever reason I'm getting some odd results.

Task association

```
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to'
```

User association

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, :class_name => 'Task', :foreign_key => 'assigned_to'
```

yet when I look at the sql being produced when a task is saved, it returns nil for the assigned_to id (it's an integer column).. and then when the Tasks/Index action is being called, I see it's attempting to pull a user where the id = null as it was saved with a null value in the field..

I've most likely done something wrong as I'm new to rails, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us more code? Maybe from the controller

Answer (score 1):

I was doing two things wrong:

1. When I created the select tag, I forgot to include the `:user` portion so when the parameters were passed in, the user's id was outside of the user object.
2. The belongs_to :assigned_to has the same name as the database column; when the parameters did come in properly once the select field was fixed, it was complaining about the value passed in not being an object. User expected, received string etc etc.  Switching the association name fixed this, which makes 100% sense and why I should definitely change the database field name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need _id with the fk

```
:foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id'
```

I am assuming your db column name is assigned_to_id

Also, this is a really good resource http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: the column is named 'assigned_to' at the moment which is why i set the foreign_key to that.. as I was under the impression that rails would just take the associated model and add an "_id" to the end of it.. unless you manually set the foreign_key.

Comment: If you have the option of renaming the column, I would.